# Modify value of non static variable - reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

have a non-static int variable define in:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @SharedField(key = "sample")
    public  int data = 2;

    SharedBind sharedBind = new SharedBind();

    @SharedMethod(key = "sample")
    public void methodTest() {
        Log.e("test", "" + data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sharedBind.bind(this); // to run the binding

}

public void onButtonClick(){
sharedBind.runTest("sample");
}
}
```

and this is from SharedBind

```
public class SharedBind  {

HashMap<String, ArrayList<BindHandler>> fieldBindHandlerHashMap = new HashMap();
HashMap<String, ArrayList<BindHandler>> methodBindHandlerHashMap = new HashMap();

public void bind(Object target) {

    Class<?> obj = target.getClass();
    for (Method method : obj.getDeclaredMethods()) {

        // if method is annotated with @Test
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(SharedMethod.class)) {


            Annotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(SharedMethod.class);
            SharedMethod sharedMethod = (SharedMethod) annotation;
            ArrayList<BindHandler> methodBindHandlers = methodBindHandlerHashMap.get(sharedMethod.key());
            if (methodBindHandlers == null)
                methodBindHandlers = new ArrayList<>();

            methodBindHandlers.add(new BindHandler(method, target, sharedMethod));

            methodBindHandlerHashMap.put(sharedMethod.key(), methodBindHandlers);
        }

    }
    for (Field field : obj.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(SharedField.class)) {
            Annotation annotation = field.getAnnotation(SharedField.class);
            SharedField sharedView = (SharedField) annotation;
            ArrayList<BindHandler> fieldBindHandlers = fieldBindHandlerHashMap.get(sharedView.key());
            if (fieldBindHandlers == null)
                fieldBindHandlers = new ArrayList<>();
            fieldBindHandlers.add(new BindHandler(field, target, sharedView));
            fieldBindHandlerHashMap.put(sharedView.key(), fieldBindHandlers);
            Log.e("done", "mdf");

            Log.e("result", field.getGenericType().toString());

        }
    }
}
   public void runTest(String key) {

    ArrayList<BindHandler> viewBinds = fieldBindHandlerHashMap.get(key);
    if (viewBinds != null) {
        for (BindHandler bindHandler : viewBinds) {
            bindHandler.getTargetField().setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    bindHandler.getTargetField().setInt(bindHandler.getTarget(), 234);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    ArrayList<BindHandler> methodBinds = methodBindHandlerHashMap.get(key);
    if (methodBinds != null) {
        for (BindHandler bindHandler : methodBinds) {
            try {
                bindHandler.getMethod().invoke(bindHandler.getTarget().getClass().newInstance());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and this is from `BindHandler`

```
public class BindHandler {
    private Field targetField;
    private OperationType operationType;
    private SharedObj sharedObj;
    private Method method;
    private Object target;


    public BindHandler(Field targetField, Object target, SharedField sharedView) {
        this.targetField = targetField;
        this.target = target;
        this.sharedObj = sharedView.dataType();
        this.operationType = sharedView.operationType();
    }
}
```

and I am trying to modify the content as:

```
bindHandler.getTargetField().setInt(bindHandler.getTarget(), 234);
```

This doesn't work. but when I change the variable in the MainActivity to :

```
@fields(key = "sample")
static public  int data = 2;
```

It works. How do make it work for non-static variable. Thanks

Comment: "This doesn't work" doesn't give us any information about what happens. We don't know what `bindHandler` is either. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are using non-JDK API and you haven't disclosed which API it is or, if custom, its implementation.

Comment: @JonSkeet  Just made an update.

Comment: I'm still not seeing a [mcve]. Hint: if we can't copy/paste/compile/run, it's incomplete...

Comment: How do you know that “it doesn’t work”?

Comment: @VGR the runTest Method is called to log the value of the variable. Please check the updated question

Comment: @JonSkeet , what about now (made another update).?

Comment: Well now it appears to be Android-specific, despite not mentioning Android anywhere... and it's really rather large. There's no need to go into annotations etc, just to reproduce the problem - and I'd *start* with a desktop console app. That's likely to be ~20 lines of code, tops.

Comment: I ask again:  How do you know it doesn’t work?  Are you seeing an exception?

Comment: figured out it was a mistake from me... bindHandler.getMethod().invoke(bindHandler.getTarget().getClass().newInstance()); called a new instance of the target instead of bindHandler.getMethod().invoke(bindHandler.getTarget());